# Is there an easy download URL for a specific version of kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes

The [Kubernetes manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) has a two-liner shell command to download the latest ´kubectl´ release, but that is rarely what companies are running. So each time I onboard a new developer I have to go to [Kubernetes Github releases page](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases), find the latest minor version that works with my cluster, copy-paste it (taking care not to forget the little "v") and manually craft the download URL.
This fiddling around makes it hard to grow a newcomer's enthusiasm for the new Kubernetes world that they are about to enter. Is there any ready-made tool or link to make that process easier?

Comment: so there are also download links when clicking from the releases page to the changelog, like this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.18.md#downloads-for-v1188  Those need to be unpacked at the client, but at least it's an improvement...

Answer (score 1):

```
Assuming you are talking about Linux as OS.
```

According to [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57748) a client can lead server by up to 2 minor versions. This more or less can make the version you want the developers to run predictable. Once you know the exact version, you can craft a chain of shell commands that can do the rest.

```
sudo curl -Lo /usr/local/bin/kubectl https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.16.15/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

However if you don't know the version in advance then I'm afraid you will have to look it up or use latest.

Answer (score 1):

You can always install with snap https://snapcraft.io/kubectl